Functions as variables in Camunda
It is well known that functions are values in javascript, and so they can be assigned to variables.
For example
var sum = function(a,b){return a+b;}
sum(1,2);

makes sense perfectly.
Now the question is:
Is it possible to set a function as a process variable in Camunda for later use in various script task components and avoid duplication?
